# Need some explanation about linux kernel wait queues

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel

I need to write some kernel module for my university classes and now I'm trying to understand various kernel mechanisms that I have to use. One of them are **wait queues**. I wrote a simple module that registers a `/proc` entry and does some simple logic inside its `read` function:

```
DECLARE_WAIT_QUEUE_HEAD(event);

volatile int condvar = 0;
volatile int should_wait = 1;

int simple_read_proc(char *page, char **start, off_t offset, int count, int *eof, void *data) {
    printk(KERN_INFO "simple_read_proc from %i\n", current->pid);
    if(should_wait == 1) {
        printk(KERN_INFO "Waiting in %i\n", current->pid);
        should_wait = 0;
        wait_event_interruptible(event, condvar == 1);
        printk(KERN_INFO "Wait finished in %i\n", current->pid);
        condvar = 0;
        return sprintf(page, "%s", "The wait has finished!\n");
    } else {
        printk(KERN_INFO "Waking up in %i\n", current->pid);
        condvar = 1;
        wake_up_interruptible(&event);
        return sprintf(page, "%s", "Woke up the other process!\n");
    }
}
```

This is what happens when I try to run `cat` twice on the registered `/proc` file:

First `cat` process waits for the second one to wake him up. Second `cat` process does exactly that. Each process prints what it should. So far, everything as planned. But then I look into `dmesg` and that is what I see:

```
[11405.484168] Initializing proc_module
[11413.209535] simple_read_proc from 6497
[11413.209543] Waiting in 6497
[11415.498482] simple_read_proc from 6499
[11415.498489] Waking up in 6499
[11415.498507] simple_read_proc from 6499
[11415.498514] Wait finished in 6497
[11415.498518] Waking up in 6499
[11415.498546] simple_read_proc from 6497
[11415.498550] Waking up in 6497
[11415.498554] simple_read_proc from 6497
[11415.498557] Waking up in 6497
[11415.498689] simple_read_proc from 6499
[11415.498694] Waking up in 6499
[11415.498753] simple_read_proc from 6497
[11415.498757] Waking up in 6497
```

My question is: why the `simple_read_proc` function was invoked so many times? I thought that this may be because `cat` invoked `read` many times, but I checked it with `strace` and this is not the case - each `cat` invoked `read` only once.

I would be grateful for some explanation of this phenomenon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the comment in `fs/proc/generic.c` about "How to be a proc read function."  Since you are not changing `eof`, the loop in `__proc_file_read` will call your `read_proc` function multiple times.